# Can this be taken as a derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to2} \frac{\sqrt{f(x)}-2}{x-2}$$ Can this be taken as the derivative of $\sqrt{f(x)}$ at $x=2$? I think it can, but I'm not sure. This is part of a larger problem which I'm working on. Thanks!

Comment: You would want $\sqrt{f(2)}$, so $\frac{\sqrt{f(x)}-\sqrt{f(2)}}{x-2}$. So it is the expression for the derivative only if $f(2)$ happens to be $4$.

Comment: Well it is the limit as x approaches 2.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Wouldn't it be $\sqrt{f(2)}$?

Comment: Yes, I realized the "$f(2)$" was either imprecise, or, more precisely, wrong. So edited within the $5$ minute limit. Whew!

Comment: Haha yes I forgot to say that f(2) does happen to be 4. However, if I take this as the derivative, I'm getting a wrong answer for my problem. I'll try to fix it, if not I'll probably post it on here later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative of $\sqrt{f(x)}$ at $x=2$ is, by definition,
$$\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{\sqrt{f(x)} -\sqrt{f(2)}}{x-2}.$$

So your expression gives the derivative of $\sqrt{f(x)}$ at $x=2$ only if $f(2)$ happens to be $4$.

Comment: Yup, as I said before I forgot to mention that f(2)=4.

Comment: That does make a difference! But that possibility was already covered in the answer.